# oracle PL SQL positive number subtype

Tags: oracle, plsql, subtype

I want to create a positive number(6, 2) subtype.
For this, I tried:

```
declare
    subtype st_positive_number is number(6, 0) > 0;
    v_positive_number positive(6, 2);
begin 
    null;
end;
```

but none of the above tries works.
Can someone help, please?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but according to the Oracle documentation: `subtype st_positive_number is number(6, 2) range 0.00..999999.99`

Comment: You can have a positive integer (via the built-in `positive` subtype of `pls_integer`), or a [constrained subtype](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-data-types.html#GUID-FDC366F3-66AA-4F6A-A59B-5A08DCBD4F9F) which specifies precision/scale - but not both at once. What will you use this for?

Comment: @Abra - you can have `number(6,2)` *or* `number range ...` but not both at once, unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I did state it was basically a guess :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to constrain the subtype with a range and you want to assign that subtype to the variable, e.g.:

```
declare
    subtype st_positive_number is PLS_INTEGER RANGE 0..999999;
    v_positive_number st_positive_number;
begin 
    v_positive_number := 999999;
end;
/
```

Comment: But the question refers to `number(6, 2)`, not integers? Well, most of the time... one attempt is `number(6, 0)`...

Comment: yeah, I thought I saw `number(6,2)` and then `number(6, 0)`; obviously I was looking at different bits of the OP's block at different times, d'oh!

Comment: Presumably the OP will undo that if it turns out my answer does not, in fact, answer their question!

Answer (score 1):

How would you want to use it? If it is about creating a table whose column accepts only positive numbers, then create a check constraint, e.g.

```
SQL> create table test (id number constraint ch_pos check (id > 0))

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (100);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (-100);
insert into test (id) values (-100)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_POS) violated
```

If that's not what you are looking for, could you explain it a little bit further, please?